# how to click on an element which comes io existance after saving it

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have created a template and want to publish it, but the issue arising i.e don't know the element of the newly generated element(template) as we have just saved and I want to access the newly saved element, how to access it?

Comment: share relevant HTML code in your question to better understanding.

Comment: Maybe get a list of all the elements of that type before creating the new one, and again after, so the difference of the two lists is the new element?

Comment: HTML code cant do anything, as the issue is regarding how to access  the element which is just created within the test script @Bhavin Dholakiya